# How to get the XPath for all tables in a page?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

How do I know or find the `xpath` for table?  Or, even better, *get* the `xpath` for all tables in a specific page?

I'm getting [no_such_element](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.jsp) when running:

```
    public void test() {

        String tableID = p.getProperty("tableID");

        log.info(tableID);

        WebElement Webtable = driver.findElement(By.id("TableID")); // Replace TableID with Actual Table ID or Xpath
        List<WebElement> TotalRowCount = Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + tableID + "']/tbody/tr"));

        log.info("No. of Rows in the WebTable: " + TotalRowCount.size());
        // Now we will Iterate the Table and print the Values   
        int RowIndex = 1;
        for (WebElement rowElement : TotalRowCount) {
            List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount = rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
            int ColumnIndex = 1;
            for (WebElement colElement : TotalColumnCount) {
                log.info("Row " + RowIndex + " Column " + ColumnIndex + " Data " + colElement.getText());
                ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex + 1;
            }
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
        }

    }
```

general context:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6198947/262852

https://stackoverflow.com/q/32864336/262852

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10323884/262852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all tables then just grab the tables like `findElements(By.xpath("//table"));` and pull all the tables back.  You can step through the list and then adjust to the table ID in question and add the tr for a new list of rows like `findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='table_id']//tr"))`.

In general that looks like what you are trying for.  Not all tables have the tbody tag in them so it's best to just xquery search `//` inside the table for each row/cell (tr/td) that you want and avoid using full xpath.

Comment: How do I get a list of all the table id s?  What about tables with out table id?

Comment: You grab the id's by looping through.  If you don't have an id choose a different criteria that is unique.  Without the HTML it's hard to say what is unique, but whatever uniquely identifies the table is the goal.  You can check id and then something else if you need to while you loop.